# Multiple Operator() Overloading in same Class

Tags: c++, class, sorting, priority-queue

I'm having a problem sorting two data structures in one class. One data structure is an array of vectors. I'm successfully using the std::sort routine on this data structure. To do this, I am overloading operator().

I want to use a priority queue on another data member and member function of the same class. However, to do that I have been trying to overload operator(), but get an error message from my compiler (g++ in the Orwell Fork version of Dev-C++) stating that I cannot overload operator() again. I can understand the logic behind this.

So, my question is: can I use both the std::sort routine and a priority queue used to sort data in the same class?

Thank you.

Edit for additional information:

I have two classes, a computer class and a PCB class.

In the PCB class is a function called "getTau," and a function called "getDiskTime." I want to sort my output in one area by obtaining the least to greatest getTau value. In the other area, I want to sort my output by least to greatest getDiskTime value. I'm building an operating system simulation, and these are processes I'm sorting and outputting basically. This is the code I am using successfully at this point:

```
#include <algorithm>...

class computer
{
    ...
    vector<PCB> readyQueue[9];
    ...
    bool operator() ( PCB p1, PCB p2 )
{
    return p1.getTau() < p2.getTau();
}
    ...
} t ;
```

And in another member function of class computer, I am calling the sort function:

```
std::sort ( readyQueue.begin(), readyQueue.end(), t );
```

And everything is working well.

As you might imagine I have a PCB class with a data member called tau which getTau returns. In that same PCB class I have a data member named diskTime which getDiskTime returns. I am trying to sort that in a disk queue I have in the computer class.

I have tried many things such as placing this in the PCB class:

```
bool operator < ( PCB & p1)
{
return p1.getDiskTime() < this->getDiskTime();

}
```

But when I return the value of diskTime is a few outputs of that queue, diskTime is not sorted by lowest value first.

I can give more information if that will help. Thank you.

Comment: Just give your comparison function directly to std::sort.

Comment: The [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function can take anything callable as a comparison function. Just be careful when attempting to use non-static member functions (might want to read about [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for that).

Comment: Thank you both. I can't seem to get the std:sort to work on both comparisons though, just one or the other.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? Can't be sorted 2 different ways at once

Comment: Kiroxas, sorry for the confusion. I will try to post code snippets later (I am at work and cannot now). I am trying to compare one thing and have that always compare that within my program. In addition to that, I am trying to sort another thing and have that always work concurrently. So, again trying to sort two different things using two different sort routines in the same class in the same program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the operator in the class and `sort` will use it.

```
struct Model
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator < (const Model &obj) const
    {
        return y < obj.y;
    }
};
```

To compare using a different criteria use another comparer for the priority queue.

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator () (const Model &a, const Model &b) const
    {
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
priority_queue<Model, vector<Model>, cmp> queue;
```

Comment: Thank you agarwaen. I will try this later when I have access to my program.

Comment: @smitsky No problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just tried your priority queue method, and it works! Thank you!!